# FIM is missing - how to get it back!

Tags: forefront

We were trying to configure our User Profile Service Synchronization (Enterprise 2010), and when the guides call for the use of FIM, we went to use it and found that the entire directory at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell` is empty!

I know this is abnormal, for I have a dev server that is full of dlls as well the infamous miisclient.exe that I want.

Question is now, how do I get FIM on my server?  (It *used* to be there!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - I figured it out...  That directory was empty because when I set up this server, I created the D: drive as a "data partition" and designated it for the location of Sharepoint Server.  So I found the FIM here:

```
D:\SharePointServer2010\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe
```